# How can I connect to my database using erlang-mysql-driver?

Tags: mysql, database, erlang

I am attempting to use [erlang-mysql-driver](https://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver) to connect to my MySQL database but am not having any luck.

I am using the following Erlang code to connect

```
mysql:start_link(p1,"localhost","myname","mypass","stocks").
```

The error message I get is:

```
mysql_recv:108: mysql_recv: Failed connecting to "localhost":3306 : {error,
                                                                 econnrefused}
mysql_conn:361: failed connecting to "localhost":3306 : {error,
                                                     "connect failed : {error,econnrefused}"}
mysql:511: failed starting first MySQL connection handler, exiting
** exception exit: {badfun,undefined}
 in function  mysql:start_reconnect/2
 in call from mysql:init/1
 in call from gen_server:init_it/6
 in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This ended up being a MySQL configuration error, unrelated to Erlang drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this driver (https://github.com/Eonblast/Emysql) and do all as in docs - and all works fine.

Comment: I tried using your driver and it gave me {failed_to_connect_to_database,econnrefused} error. Is that something to do with MySQL configuration?

Comment: Try to connect to your MySQL DB with desktop client with your settings. Also maybe you should grant permissions to connect from localhost.

Comment: Modify your MySQL DB settings and try again